# Qt5 on Windows 7 Arial font: Thai is very small

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, qt5, porting

I am attempting to port our desktop application from Qt 4.8.4 to Qt 5.2.1.  On Windows, I've found that Thai text displayed with Arial is much smaller in a `QPlainTextEdit` than it was under Qt4.  In fact, it is too small to read.

I load the Thai file into our application running under Qt4, and it is fine.  On the same Windows 7 x64 machine, I load the file into my Qt5 version of our application, and the text is illegibly small.

Incidentally, normal English text using the same font and the same `QPlainTextEdit` is the same legible size for both the Qt4 and Qt5 versions of our application.

Is this a bug in Qt5?  Or maybe there's something tricky about porting to Qt5 involving `QFont` or `QPlainTextEdit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-40372).  This is fixed in Qt 5.4.0.